# What does hash sign # do in the C# especially in if-else Statements?

Tags: c#

I came across the following code as shown below. But I couldn't understand how # can be worked in c#?

```
 using System;
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        #if (!pi)
                    Console.WriteLine("i");
        #else 
                    Console.WriteLine("PI undefined");
        #endif
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
i
ok
```

Comment: See: ["C# preprocessor directives"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C# the lines starting with `#` are [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) (and they must be the only instruction on the line).

When the C# compiler encounters an [`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) directive, followed eventually by an [`#endif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-endif) directive, it compiles the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.

*N.B.* Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol. The `#if` statement in C# is `Boolean` and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler does not have a separate preprocessor. however, 
the directives are processed as if there was one. In C# the preprocessor directives are used to
 help in conditional compilation. Unlike C and C++ directives, they are not used to create macros. 
A preprocessor directive must be the only instruction on a line.

The `#define` preprocessor directive creates symbolic constants.
`#define` lets you define a symbol such that, by using the symbol as the expression passed to the
 `#if` directive, the expression evaluates to true. Its syntax is as follows.

When the C# compiler encounters an `#if` directive, followed eventually by an `#endif` directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined. the `#if` statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or no.

```
#define pi 

using System;

namespace Sample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        #if (!pi)
            Console.WriteLine("i");
        #else
            Console.WriteLine("PI undefined");
        #endif
        Console.WriteLine("ok");
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```